# Reading from JSON array in a file and can't access the array or push into i

Tags: javascript, json

```
$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {
var array = [];

for (var key in json) {

    var item = json[key];

    array.push({

       name: item.player.player-name ,
       position: item.player.player-stats.position,
       yd: item.player.player-stats.passing-yards,
       pa: item.player.player-stats.passing-touchdowns,

    });            
}
}    
);
```

json file

```
{ "players": [
{"player":{
        "player-name":"Cam Newton",
        "player-stats":{
            "position":"QB",
            "passing-yards":226,
            "passing-touchdowns":3


        }
}
},
{"player":{
    "player-name":"Aaron Rodgers",
    "player-stats":{
        "position":"QB",
        "passing-yards":327,
        "passing-touchdowns":3,


    }
}
}}
```

Comment: please take your time and make your question nice. make the code look good, also show the code you tried and which failed, and explain exactly how it failed (what you expect/want to happen, and what actually happens, including error messages)

Comment: Could you post what error messages you're receiving?

Comment: It's first time for me posting on here that's why it's a mess

Comment: And there is no error message it just not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

> `
>    you used :item.player.player-stats.position . you are getting an error when access a variable reason is - sign use in variable name user.
>   if you use - sing then you can access using  ["player-stats.position"].
>   shown in example:

Json formate :

```
 var json = {
        "players": {
                    "player": {
                        "player-name": "Cam Newton",
                        "player-stats": {
                            "position": "QB",
                            "passingYards": 226,
                            "passingTouchdowns": 3


                        }
                    },
                "player": {
                    "player-name": "Aaron Rodgers",
                    "player-stats": {
                        "position": "QB",
                        "passingYards": 327,
                        "passingTouchdowns": 3,
                    }

                }
            }

};
```

//code  it may be helpful for you.

```
var array = [];
for (var key in json) {
       var item = json[key];
        for (var key in item) {
            var test = item[key];
            array.push({
               name: test["player-name"] ,
               position: test["player-stats"].position,
               yd: test["player-stats"].passingYards,
               pa: test["player-stats"].passingTouchdowns,

    }); 


    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing make your JSON Valid . here i updated the valid JSON :

```
{
"players": {
    "player": {
        "player-name": "Aaron Rodgers",
        "player-stats": {
            "position": "QB",
            "passingYards": 327,
            "passingTouchdowns": 3
        }
    }
}
}
```